# mismatch between working days and business days in matlab

Tags: matlab, date

I were calculating the number of working days between two dates

> > date_1=733943;
> >
> > date_2=734152;
> >
> > wrk_dy_dif=wrkdydif(date_1,date_2)
> >
> > wrk_dy_dif =
> >
> > 150

i tried to build a days vector based the previous dates and expect to get a 150X1 vector
but i actually got a 145X1 vector

> > bus_days=busdays(date_1,date_2);
> >
> > size(bus_days)
> >
> > ans =
> >
> > 145     1

does anybody know why is that and how can i fix it ?
thx in advance for your kind help

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, [`busdays`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/busdays.html) will assume USA public holidays unless you tell it not to. [`wrkdydif`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/wrkdydif.html) does not. So there is nothing to fix, just pick the one that is relevant to you and don't use both.